# Is there a way to make a checkbox read only but enable it if the probability of an opportunity is 95 or more?

Tags: custom-field

Is there a way to make a checkbox read only but enable it if the probability of an opportunity is 95 or more?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!
Rommel

Answer (score 8):

Possible work around is to write a validation rule preventing check-box being changed unless probability is above 95%.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do exactly what you want, but you could achieve the desired outcome through the use of a formula field.

i.e. rather than basing processes off the value of the checkbox, base them off a formula field which does the following (assuming you want it unchecked by default, swap for true otherwise):

```
IF(Probability >= 0.95, Checkbox__c, false)
```

Also I'm not 100% if probability should be 0.95 or 95, but I'll leave that up to you ;)

Comment: But then the field is always read-only.

Comment: Ah no, I mean for the checkbox itself to be read/write, the formula basically acts as the real value to use. The checkbox however determines its value if the probability is >= 95%, otherwise the checkbox is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different page layouts, where the checkbox is read-only or editable. Then create two recordtypes for Opportunity, and have the recordtype automatically change when the Stage gets to a certain point. When the recordtype changes, the new page layout will be used, and the checkbox will now be editable.